# Redirecting user-login-form on certain page

Tags: 7, forms, redirection

The scenario is :

I've implemented a menu using hook_menu and in that page it checks if user have access to creating certain content type (called request) if he/she does have access it will load content creation page using drupal_get_form else it checks if user is not logged in, in this case it loads user_login_block, again with drupal_get_form function, finally if user is logged in and still does not have access to create content type, it shows a message about that.

the problem is :
I want user redirect to this same page after login, it redirects to user/uid by default.

This is the code for my page provider function :

```
Global $user;
$content = "";
if(user_access('create request content')){
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$node_form = new stdClass;
$node_form->type = 'request';
$node_form->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$form = drupal_get_form("request_node_form", $node_form);
$content .= drupal_render($form);
}
else
if($user->uid == 0) {
  $login_form = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
  $login_form['redirect'] = drupal_get_destination();//What I did to get form redirected, but no chance
  $content = '<p>For better controlling on your project flow consider signing in before submitting your file.</p>';      
  $content .= drupal_render($login_form);
}
else
  $content = "Unfortunately only user of role customer can submit a request.report any problem by sending email to --------";
return $content;
```

I also tried [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) but it neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods to redirect user to specified url after login

You can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

```
Events: User has logged in.<br/>
Condition: User has role<br/>
Actions: Page redirect<br/><br/>
```

Another one with drupal api:

```
   function hook_user_login(&$edit, $account) {   
     $edit['redirect'] = 'yourpath';
  }
```

**if it not worked** try to change `$GLOBALS['destination']` with

```
function hook_user_login(&$edit, $account)  {
  $GLOBALS['destination'] = 'yourpath';
}
```

Also you can use [Login Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_redirect)

> Overview A simple module providing a method to redirect users
>   according to an URL-defined parameter after logging in. Allows
>   redirects toward non-Drupal location.
>
> Features
>
> ```
> Lightweight and minimal configuration. No module dependencies!
> Allows custom URL parameter name
> Filters XSS URL input
> ```